# Ubuntu Linux: How to count the numbers of certain files in a directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I know how to count the numbers of all files in a directory with linux

```
command:ls -l . | egrep -c '^-'.
```

If there are `test_1.jpg, train_1.jpg, test_2.jpg, train_1.jpg .....` in the directory. I just want to count the numbers of `test_*jpg` and don't count the numbers of `train_*.jpg` in this directory. How to use the Linux command to do it. thanks!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146760/count-files-in-a-directory-by-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find `ls -1 |> wc -l` works well. Note that is minus one and not minus letter l.

EDIT:

So, in your case `ls -1 test*.jpg | wc -l` should work. You can tune the wildcards. In this case, it will match anything starting with `test` and ending with `.jpg`.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I just want to count the number  of test_*.jpg  not include train_*.jpg

Comment: Updated the answer for for that. Actually, I did not include the underscore, so perhaps you want the glob to be `test_*.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work for you:

```
ls -l *train_*.jpg | egrep -c '^-'.
```

Comment: This certainly worked in my own tests with similar data to yours.

Answer (score 1):

If all your file were in the same directory `dir`, the following command will help you.

```
ll dir/test_*.jpg | wc -l
ls -al dir/test_*.jpg | wc -l
```

Explaination:

```
ls -al dir/test_*.jpg | wc -l

# ll is short for ls -al
# -l    use a long listing format
# -a, --all
#       do not hide entries starting with .

# wc -l print the newline counts.
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your filenames contain no spaces

```
a=( test*.jpg ); echo ${#a[@]}
```

Also check `shopt nullglob` to detect empty lists.

Comment: Or set `IFS=$'\n'` before filling the array and don't worry about the spaces. I would probably do that and change `echo` to `find . -type f -printf "%f\n"`